# retrieve intermediate features from a pipeline in Scikit (Python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am using a pipeline very similar to the one given [in this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#building-a-pipeline) :

```
>>> text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
...                      ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
...                      ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
... ])
```

over which I use `GridSearchCV` to find the best estimators over a parameter grid.

However, I would like to get the column names of my training set with the `get_feature_names()` method from `CountVectorizer()`. Is this possible without implementing `CountVectorizer()` outside the pipeline?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the `get_params()` function, you can get access at the various parts of the pipeline and their respective internal parameters. Here's an example of accessing `'vect'`

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('clf', MultinomialNB())]
print text_clf.get_params()['vect']
```

yields (for me)

```
CountVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', binary=False, decode_error=u'strict',
    dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=u'utf-8', input=u'content',
    lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
    ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
    strip_accents=None, token_pattern=u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
    tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)
```

I haven't fitted the pipeline to any data in this example, so calling `get_feature_names()` at this point will return an error.

Answer (score 4):

just for reference

```
The estimators of a pipeline are stored as a list in the steps attribute:
>>>

>>> clf.steps[0]
('reduce_dim', PCA(copy=True, n_components=None, whiten=False))

and as a dict in named_steps:
>>>

>>> clf.named_steps['reduce_dim']
PCA(copy=True, n_components=None, whiten=False)
```

from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html