# Text Classification with scikit-learn: how to get a new document's representation from a pickle model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, tf-idf, document-classification

I have a document binomial classifier that uses a *tf-idf* representation of a training set of documents and applies Logistic Regression to it:

```
lr_tfidf = Pipeline([('vect', tfidf),('clf', LogisticRegression(random_state=0))])

lr_tfidf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I save the model in pickle and used it to classify new documents:

```
text_model = pickle.load(open('text_model.pkl', 'rb'))
results = text_model.predict_proba(new_document)
```

How can I get the representation (features + frequencies) used by the model for this new document without explicitly computing it?

EDIT: I am trying to explain better what I want to get.
Wen I use predict_proba, I guess that the new document is represented as a vector of term frequencies (according to the rules used in the model stored) and those frequencies are multiplied by the coefficients learnt by the logistic regression model to predict the class. Am I right? If yes, how can I get the terms and term frequencies of this new document, as used by predict_proba?

I am using sklearn v 0.19

Comment: Tfidf is traditionally a BOW vector of term freq times document freq. You might be able to decompose the raw counts from the tfidf internal object data.

Comment: Can you provide code? The raw count is not enough, though ... I need the actual tfidf value for each term of the document.

Comment: If you are pickling the pipeline, then it contains the tfidf model as `vect` so you can just use it!

Comment: when you pickle the pipeline, it only contains the documents in the training set not new_document.

Comment: TF-IDF vectors are made from a corpus (training data), i am not sure what you are looking for

Comment: it's explained in the edit part, I need the representation of an additional document (not part of the training set) that needs to be classified. I doubt the training is executed again when I call predict_proba().

Comment: the tfidf vectorizer in sklearn, which i believe is part of the pipeline, can transform the input into a tfidf vector for any new input.

Comment: yes it does, but how can I explicitly call the vectorizer? Can you provide code?

Comment: sounds like your question is really a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085806/retrieve-intermediate-features-from-a-pipeline-in-scikit-python

Comment: @Eugenio Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, thanks, your answer has been accepted and commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from the comments, you need to access the tfidfVectorizer from inside the pipeline. This can be done easily by:

```
tfidfVect = text_model.named_steps['vect']
```

Now you can use the [`transform()` method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.transform) of the vectorizer to get the tfidf values.

```
tfidf_vals = tfidfVect.transform(new_document)
```

The `tfidf_vals` will be a sparse matrix of single row containing the tfidf of terms found in the `new_document`. To check what terms are present in this matrix, you need to use `tfidfVect.get_feature_names()`.

Comment: From the comments, this would be the answer that @eugenio is looking for, I agree. Get the step in the pipeline you want and use it to vectorize.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed. The only problem was with some additional preprocessing activity (e.g. custom stemmers) that are saved in the model but not accessible from tfidfVect, I think the easiest solution is to apply them before fitting. Question: am I right when I say that by multiplying each of the tfidf I got with the corresponding logistic regression coefficient I can say how much that term impacts on classifying the new document as class 1 ? It is a binomial classifier, available categories are 0 or 1.